# How to merge SeaWiFS and MODIS data or use other merged products?

Tags: python, data, remote-sensing, modis

I hope to produce a time-series for sea surface temperature (SST) and chlorophyll-a (Chl-a) for use in [MaxEnt](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/maxent/) without the use of [arcgis](/questions/tagged/arcgis), preferring Python tools to others. I am new to satellite data processing, and there appears to be quite a lot to consider.

What must be taken into account for merging SeaWiFS and MODIS datasets (e.g. discrepancies between the data, projections, etc.)?

Are there other products available that provide such merged data that are generally recommended?

I have found the following:

- [NOAA - CoRTAD (SST)](http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/sog/Cortad/)
- [ESA - MEDSPIRATION (SST)](http://projets.ifremer.fr/cersat/Information/Projects/MEDSPIRATION2/Background)
- [ESA - GlobColour (SST & Chl-a)](http://www.globcolour.info/products_description.html)

Ultimately I need all of the data gridded to the same grid size/area, so I would to write a script where I could acquire the data, re-project if necessary, re-sample to the grid if necessary, and then save to desired format (ESRI's ASCII .asc) for running in the model.

Comment: This is an old question. Anyhow, if you are still around, would you mind to explain "merging" SeaWiFS and MODIS data? What exactly is/was the purpose of this task?

Comment: Each dataset has different temporal coverage, but due to differences between the sensors, they cannot be compared apples to apples. The products I mentioned above merge these data sets using different averaging/interpolation methods, but I just wanted to see if anybody had their own methods for using these data sets together.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I (only) think that the action of "merging" should be clearly described as it might refer to different actions (e.g. Pan sharpening, some Fusion process, other statistical aggregation, et.c.). I am not familiar with SeaWiFS data. Nevertheless, if the various products to be "merged", measure the same "thing", it is possible to (cross-sensor-)compare them after carefully and in a scientifically sound manner, bring them to the same units. I.e., Surface Reflectances, "corrected" for atmospheric effects and relatively normalised so as to be comparable? I guess...

Comment: ...that the bandwidths shouldn't differ too much though. Maybe check the differences, search for publications on the subject. It might be possible.